# SLD for OpenStreetMap for GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, sld

I display OpenStreetMap with some SLD styles.

[image: my OSM]

This map is not the same OSM.

I want that this map is equal OSM map.

I use GeoServer 2.3.5

[Does anyone display OpenStreetMap through MapServer, ArcGIS for Server or Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70641/does-anyone-display-osm-through-mapserver-arcgisserver-or-geoserver) - here are some ideas.

**Update:** The map may be not relevant OSM map. But it must be beautiful.

Comment: Some updates on this?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are referring to [this one](https://github.com/FlorentDotMe/archives/tree/master/2013.03.23-OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer)?

Since you know exactly what you want the map to look like, I would suggest starting with either the linked SLD from this post or the one from @tmcw.  Then you can edit it until the map visualization fits your needs.

You could even post the results to github and share them with the community.

Answer (score 2):

[openstreetmap-sld](https://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld) gets close to the original style, but nothing will match exactly since OSM is not styled with SLD.

Comment: Thanks, but this sld styles are very old. Is there new sld (not relevant Mapnik styles) which gives beatiful map.

Comment: Can you tell me about the style that OSM or Google map uses?