# Does anyone display OpenStreetMap through MapServer, ArcGIS for Server or Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, openstreetmap, mapserver, style

I use Windows OS. The data (OpenStreetMap) are stored in a postgres/postgis database.

How do I display this data correctly?

**Update:** Now I use: geoserver-2.3.5.exe, postgresql-9.1.9-1-windows-x64.exe, postgis-pg91x64-setup-2.0.3-2.exe, osm2pgsql

**Update2** I lookd at the source for "osminabox". https://git.hsr.ch/index.html#repositoryBrowser;26067c88-f4a8-46e8-be0d-95c1a5091c94;null;Code/osm2gis/geoserver/geoserver_data/styles

1. But I find many sld styles (I have only 4 layers: planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_roads).
2. There are a lot of styles for points: osm_poi.sld, osm_building.sld, osm_pow.sld. I don't have this layer.
3. Also I find strings such: "img/recycling.png"

So, If I use intranet system I can't work?

**Update 2 continue:** 
I try to use https://github.com/fotographs/OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer/tree/master/sld. But I cannot find sld styles for the points.

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7521/geoserver-style-files - Would it help?

Comment: Which software did you use to load the data into the database?

Comment: osm2pgsql\x64

`osm2pgsql.exe -c -d gis -U postgres -H localhost -P 5432 -S default.style C:\rostov.osm.bz2`

Comment: Rather than clutter your Question with headings of Update 1, Update 2, Update 2 continue, etc, my advice would be whenever you edit your Question simply to revise it because by clicking the edited button beneath it we can see what changes were made anyway.  No such headings means the question stays more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration looks good. Now you need a Mapnik-looking-like style file for your server.

Maybe this can help you with **Geoserver**:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OSM-style-SLD-files-for-GeoServer-td5015615.html

A working set of sld files can be found in the osminabox sources:

https://github.com/justinlavelle/osm2gis/tree/master/geoserver/geoserver_data/styles

Source -> Code -> osm2gis -> geoserver -> geoserver_data -> styles

---

For **Mapserver**, you find some instructions here:

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataWindows

---

Note that the official Openstreetmap is **not** rendered by Geoserver or Mapserver, but comes as tiles created by **Mapnik**. This offers some more tweaks of better map styling, and serving ready-made tiles is a lot faster for lower zoom levels than rendering of data from a postgis database on-demand.