# Style for OSM in QGIS that can be exported to SLD

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, tiles, sld

I need some production ready styles for OSM maps, which I can export into SLD. I am looking for styles for a long time and unsuccessful, so I decide create custom style by some manual. Can you give me any advice for a book or some tutorial where I proceed how to create nice looking map style from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where download sld styles for OpenStreetMap for GeoServer?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70549/where-download-sld-styles-for-openstreetmap-for-geoserver)

Comment: I tried this and this style is prety old and current not works for me.

Comment: To prevent this being closed as a duplicate can you [edit] your question to explain in more detail why it does not answer your question.  As it stands it looks like your question is seeking a book or tutorial recommendation, which is fine for the GIS Chat Room, but too broad for the focussed Q&A of this Main GIS SE site.

Comment: You can use Mapbox Studio to create a basemap from scratch, which is completely based on OSM data.